# Openstack Instances are not pinging when they are in different network

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have created two network in openstack (Hawana -ubuntu 12.04 LTS) (192.168.1.0/28, 192.168.1.16/28) and both network have their instances. Instances can ping the gateway of another network
 but instance can not ping another instance in that network.

for example Network one: 192.168.1.0/28 gateway is 192.168.1.1 and Instance ip 192.168.1.2
 network two: 192.168.1.16/28 gateway is 192.168.1.17 and instance ip is 192.168.1.18

now 192.168.1.18 machine can ping 192.168.1.1 but not 192.168.1.2

please tell me the exact problem of it.

Comment: have you checked the if the rules of your security groups allow pinging? (http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/configure_security_groups_rules.html)

Answer (score 0):

The two networks (subnets, actually) should be connected via a single router for instances on the networks to reach each other.

And as @Brenne mentioned, ICMP packets (ping) have to be explicitly enabled in the security group. By default, they are not allowed.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have an another query regarding NIC card in my machine, two NIC cards are required for single node installation?

Comment: No, you can install a single node openstack (Devstack) on a machine with a single nic.

Comment: i have installed openstack (not devstack) in my machine and internet is not accessible on VMs. i want to ping like google.com from VM of openstack.

Comment: Can you ping an IP address directly? Try pinging 8.8.8.8 and see if you get a response. If you do, you probably did not set the DNS name servers in your subnet